# group by multiple columns in SQL/PHP, where both columns can include the same data

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a challenge in php/mySQL, that I cant find any other examples of, and is proving a bit of a challenge.

I have a table that has "category" and a "subcategory" columns. Both could contain the same data, or could be blank, eg:

```
--------------------------
| category | subcategory |
--------------------------
|   blue   |             |
|   blue   |    green    |
|  green   |     red     |
|  yellow  |     red     |
|    red   |             |
--------------------------
```

I want to group and filter these results to show a simple list of all categories used, eg:

```
blue (2)
red (3)
green (2)
yellow (1)
```

I can group and sort by one column no problem, but cant see a way how to do this including two columns.

```
SELECT category,subcategory FROM table GROUP BY category,subcategory
```

All the examples I can see online involve grouping by two columns, where the columns are different and contain different data, eg: firstname, lastname, so I dont think this is a duplication!

Thanks in advance for any thought or assistance with this!

---

edited to show current code to @bang, as per comments below:

```
$query = "SELECT category, count(*) FROM ( SELECT category from ae_test UNION ALL SELECT subcategory as 'category' from ae_test ) as t GROUP BY category";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
extract($row);
echo "$category ($count)<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: As in the post, desired output is a list of all unique words used in either/both column and not repeated, eg: blue (2)
red (3)
green (2)
yellow (1)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM table UNION SELECT DISTINCT(subcategory) FROM table;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then try this :

```
SELECT category, count(*)
FROM ( 
    SELECT category from table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT subcategory as 'category' from table
) as t GROUP BY category;
```

The first select get your category and the second your subcategory.

I use UNION ALL to get all data even if they are duplicated.

In your php please never use extract :

```
$query = "SELECT category, count(*) FROM ( SELECT category from ae_test UNION ALL SELECT subcategory as 'category' from ae_test ) as t GROUP BY category";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

     echo "$row['category'] ($row['count(*)'])<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, and does give me a unique list as desired. What does "as t GROUP" do? I have never seen that before! Also, how do I reference the count? Outputting $category ($count) give me, eg, blue (), with no count?

Comment: "t" is just an alias it's not linked with the GROUP BY. Where is  your php ?

Comment: added my current php code to the bottom of my question above, as I cant add code to a comment block.

Comment: updated ! I don't expect extract will create $count from $row['count(*)']

Comment: Have this all working now. Thank you for your time and effort.